Fantasy, weird romance movie set in a futuristic Imperial compound?
I saw the last 20 minutes or so of this movie on TV in Ireland in 2006 or 2007.
It seemed to be set in a fantasy future world, in some sort of highly guarded royal compound or palace, like a modern version of China's Forbidden City, with lots of rules and protocol.
The key characters I remember are the female dignitary, who had quite short cropped hair, dyed bright orange (or at least, she did at the end), and a male palace functionary.
The two are secretly in love it seems, and towards the end of the film the male character reveals that he has undergone some form of castration procedure, so as to become a eunuch, in order to see the female character again within the compound. They then escape together.
I seem to remember the cinematography had quite an "other-worldly" quality to it - I think mostly due to colouration. In any case, it was very unusual.
I would say it's most likely that it was a European film.
It was live action, and shot in colour, and if I had to guess I would say it was probably made some time between 1990 and 2000.
I remember the interior sets looking quite utilitarian/minimalist - not much clutter around, and it contrasted heavily with when the pair escaped, and found themselves in a very natural forest environment.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
